# Class Design : Parsers for different file type and ParserFactory

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns, spring

I have come up with a class design for parsers (for xml,csv etc) and parser factory. I will be using it in my project.I will be configuring these as beans in the spring context file. I would like to get opinion on the class design.

```
public interface Parser<T> {
    String fileFormatSupported();
    List<T> parse(File file);
    boolean supports(Class<?> clazz);
    boolean validate(File file);
}
public abstract class AbstractCSVFileParser<T> implements Parser<T>{
    private static final String FILE_FORMAT = "csv";
    @Override
    public final String fileFormatSupported() {
        return FILE_FORMAT;
    }
}
public class CSVToDeviceportServer extends AbstractCSVFileParser<DeviceportServer> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return DeviceportServer.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }
    @Override
    public  List<DeviceportServer> parse(File file) { /* logic*/ }
    @Override
    public boolean validate(File file) { /* logic */  }
}
public class CSVToDeviceParser extends AbstractCSVFileParser<Device> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Device.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }
    @Override
    public List<Device> parse(File file) {  /* logic */  }
    @Override
    public boolean validate(File file) { /* logic */ }
}
public class ParserFactory {
    @Autowired
    private List<Parser<?>> parsers;

    private Map<String, List<Parser<?>>> parserMap;

    public List<Parser<?>> getParsers() {
        return parsers;
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception{
        if(this.parsers == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Parsers not initialized");
        }
        parserMap = new HashMap<>(2);
        for(Parser<?> parser : parsers) {
            if (parserMap.containsKey(parser.fileFormatSupported())) {
                parserMap.get(parser.fileFormatSupported()).add(parser);
            }else {
                List<Parser<?>> parserList = new ArrayList<>();
                parserList.add(parser);
                parserMap.put(parser.fileFormatSupported(), parserList);
            }
        }
    }
    public Parser<?> getParser(Class<?> clazz, String format) {
        for(Parser<?> parser : parserMap.get(format)) {
            if(parser.supports(clazz)) return parser;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find parser for the format");
    }
}
```

I'm adding parser classes only for the CSV type of files, but there are other types of parsers for xml, json. They will have same class design as the CSV file parsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The method `Parser.fileFormatSupported` looks great. Letting each parser *declare* which file types it can process allows for information hiding. Android uses the same style for deciding the "Which app can handle which file types?" question.
- The method `Parser.supports` uses an inferior style. If you can, you should also switch to a declarative style by replacing this method with `Set<Class<?>> getSupportedClasses()`. Maybe you only need `Class<?> getSupportedClass()`.
- In the `supports` methods, you currently use `isAssignableFrom`. This looks wrong to me, since each of these parsers probably only supports *exactly* this one class. Therefore these methods should return `clazz == Device.class`.
- The `CSVToDeviceportServer` class is missing the `Parser` in its name.
- In the `afterPropertiesSet` method, you don't need to check for `this.parsers == null`. The code will fail in the `for` loop below. The chances of your custom exception being thrown are close to zero. And even if `this.parsers` were null, it would be very easy to see in the stack trace.
- In the `afterPropertiesSet` method, you should use a `Multimap` (from Guava) instead of a `HashMap` of lists. This makes the code shorter and easier to understand.
- Instead of the `@PostConstruct` method, you *may think about* having an `@Autowired void setParsers(List<Parser> parsers)` method that initializes everything. This method is easier to use in unit tests. This method should be package-private since it is not intended to be used by any other code.

Comment: Can you give me example on how I can replace the supports method with getSupportedClass ?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you didn't understand. Just open `Parser.java` in a text editor, remove the text `supports(Class<?> clazz)`, add the `getSupportedClasses` method. In the end, the code for checking the supported classes should look exactly like the code for checking the supported file types.